# Main menu highlighting on subpage which is not in submenu but in hierarchy

Tags: menus

I have my menu made of images. Therefore I use `divs` and with `.current-menu-item` I use CSS to change the image. This works if I'm directly on this main page. If I'm on a subpage I cannot use this trick anymore. The reason is that the submenu is build like the following:

Each page has set a parent. The submenu is generated with

```
wp_page_menu(array(
    'child_of' => SUBMENU_ROOT
));
```

whereas SUBMENU_ROOT is the fetched top most parent. So I have the parent ID which should be highlighted in the main menu. How can I achieve a highlighting of the main menu when I'm on a subpage?

Or is the only way to use the normal menu dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.current-menu-parent` and/or `.current-menu-ancestor`.